# Can't run Ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

There is no option to run from USB, The menu shows grub 2.0  and the only options available are try without installing and install Ubuntu.The boot menu is UEFI and i'm using the 12.10 x64 version.

Comment: **Try without installing** is the same thing as **run** Ubuntu from the **Live USB.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to try without installing Ubuntu.

[image: Image 1]

At this screen, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot into Ubuntu, without installing.

It will ask to install Ubuntu, but just ignore that.

Before you decide to install, make sure it dectects your Network Card etc.

**Edit**: Right, so you want to install Ubuntu from the USB to the HDD.

So, at this screen, go down to *Install Ubuntu*.

Follow the steps, and there you go. Ubuntu on the HDD.

**More Edits**: Ok, so boot from Ubuntu. Click 'Try Ubuntu'.

On the desktop, there should be a icon saying 'Install Ubuntu'.

If not, search in the Dash.

If not again, you will have to boot into Windows and download the .iso file. Then you launch the .iso and you should be able to install.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks for replying but I'm trying to run it from the usb. It's not actually showing that screen though. However, I can try it without installing and install it.

Comment: Run Ubuntu form USB? What are you running it from now?

Comment: It's trying to make me install it to my hard drive which doesn't make sense because it is already on my usb. Also I've tried multiple versions of Ubuntu and the same thing happens with all of them, including 32 and 64bit.

Comment: @user146476 - See edit to installing...

Comment: It's not showing that menu, I took a picture but I can't post it because of the fricken reputation bs. It's basically a black screen with grub 2.00 at the top and the options to install or try.

Comment: See edit again. Accept if this works. You can also give me the link on a web-site.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to ask a question when I can't show what I'm talking about, thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. It's trying to install on to your PC. It's not trying to install it on your USB.